# Extract Date and Time from a String Using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on a regex that accepts all possible formats of date and time to extract them from a sentence.

This is my Regex:

```
@"(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|(?:Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec)))\1|(?:(?:1|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2]|(?:Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)(?:0?2|(?:Feb))\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9]|(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep))|(?:1[0-2]|(?:Oct|Nov|Dec)))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})(?:[\D]*)(?<time>\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\s(?:A|P)M)";
```

Currently, the regex works perfectly when extracting time at any position in the sentence but extracts the date only if it is at the beginning of a sentence.
Also, if there is a second date in the sentence the regex does not acknowledge it but if there is text directly after it matches the text alongside the date.

For example:

```
Meet me on 31/07/2019 at 3:00 PM to celebrate and then the meeting will be on 03/08/2019 at 12:00 PM.
```

The Regex is supposed to match:

1) `31/07/2019`

2) `3:00 PM`

3) `03/08/2019`

4) `12:00 PM`

**Note:** The expected output should be extracted from any part of the sentence (Beginning, Middle, End)

Comment: Hi, You should not check if the date is valid in your regex. You will handle 31/02 out side of the regex it will be easier.

Comment: You have some `^` and `$` anchors which are definitely causing problems.  Beyond this, I would recommend taking each part of the alternation, getting it working, then piecing together the larger regex.

Comment: "all possible formats of date and time", that's a lot of possibility. A list of valid and invalid format could be. Then work each of those case by case.

Comment: @DragandDrop I cannot break down my code and do that because currently my code matches first and then extracts the matches.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have been struggling with this code for weeks and you just helped me out big time. I got rid of the anchors and the code worked. Thank you!

Comment: @DalalKurdi It still didn't work for me, even after removing those anchors, but it helped.  See my deleted answer below, which should have fired 4 matches, but only has 2.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this was my output:

Parsed 'hello meet me on 5/1/2019 6:32 PM please and then 5/2/2019 7:32 PM and then 10:25 PM' to 5/1/2019 6:32 PM.

Converted 'hello meet me on 5/1/2019 6:32 PM please and then 5/2/2019 7:32 PM and then 10:25 PM' to 05/01/2019 18:32:00.

Parsed 'hello meet me on 5/1/2019 6:32 PM please and then 5/2/2019 7:32 PM and then 10:25 PM' to 5/2/2019 7:32 PM.

Converted 'hello meet me on 5/1/2019 6:32 PM please and then 5/2/2019 7:32 PM and then 10:25 PM' to 05/02/2019 19:32:00.

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but the 508-character pattern you present here seems like an excellent candidate for [ignoring white space](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#ignore-white-space) and using newlines and indentation to make it easier to read, visualize, and potentially spot mistakes.  Not that readability is a strong suit of regular expressions to begin with, but this is about as easy to follow as entire function written on one line with no whitespace: harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex part before the `\D*` + time pattern matches various types of dates, and must be grouped before adding any other pattern to follow. That is, `(?<date>DATE1_PATTERN|DATE2_PATTERN|DATEn_PATTERN)\D*(?<time>TIME_PATTERN)`.

Then, just match and access named groups:

```
var s = "Meet me on 31/07/2019 at 3:00 PM to celebrate and then the meeting will be on 03/08/2019 at 12:00 PM.";
var pattern = @"(?<date>(?:(?:31([-/.])(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|(?:Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec)))\1|(?:(?:1|30)([-/.])(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2]|(?:Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})|(?:29([-/.])(?:0?2|Feb)\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))|(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])([-/.])(?:(?:0?[1-9]|(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep))|(?:1[0-2]|(?:Oct|Nov|Dec)))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))\D*(?<time>\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s[AP]M)";
var result = Regex.Matches(s, pattern);
foreach (Match m in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["date"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["time"].Value);
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/KauOzP), output:

```
31/07/2019
3:00 PM
03/08/2019
12:00 PM
```

Here is the [.NET regex fiddle](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3Cdate%3E%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3A31%28%5B-%2F.%5D%29%28%3F%3A0%3F%5B13578%5D%7C1%5B02%5D%7C%28%3F%3AJan%7CMar%7CMay%7CJul%7CAug%7COct%7CDec%29%29%29%5C1%7C%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3A1%7C30%29%28%5B-%2F.%5D%29%28%3F%3A0%3F%5B13-9%5D%7C1%5B0-2%5D%7C%28%3F%3AJan%7CMar%7CApr%7CMay%7CJun%7CJul%7CAug%7CSep%7COct%7CNov%7CDec%29%29%5C2%29%29%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3A1%5B6-9%5D%7C%5B2-9%5D%5Cd%29%3F%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%7C%28%3F%3A29%28%5B-%2F.%5D%29%28%3F%3A0%3F2%7CFeb%29%5C3%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3A1%5B6-9%5D%7C%5B2-9%5D%5Cd%29%3F%28%3F%3A0%5B48%5D%7C%5B2468%5D%5B048%5D%7C%5B13579%5D%5B26%5D%29%7C%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3A16%7C%5B2468%5D%5B048%5D%7C%5B3579%5D%5B26%5D%2900%29%29%29%29%7C%28%3F%3A0%3F%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5Cd%7C2%5B0-8%5D%29%28%5B-%2F.%5D%29%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3A0%3F%5B1-9%5D%7C%28%3F%3AJan%7CFeb%7CMar%7CApr%7CMay%7CJun%7CJul%7CAug%7CSep%29%29%7C%28%3F%3A1%5B0-2%5D%7C%28%3F%3AOct%7CNov%7CDec%29%29%29%5C4%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3A1%5B6-9%5D%7C%5B2-9%5D%5Cd%29%3F%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%29%5CD*%28%3F%3Ctime%3E%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%5Cs%5BAP%5DM%29&i=Meet%20me%20on%2031%2F07%2F2019%20at%203%3A00%20PM%20to%20celebrate%20and%20then%20the%20meeting%20will%20be%20on%2003%2F08%2F2019%20at%2012%3A00%20PM.&o=i).