# I need to use a REGEX to extract the Date from a string of text

Tags: c#, regex

I need to alter my regex in order to be able to extract the date without any text afterward. Currently, the regex extracts date and time but only if they come after one another. If there is text between them the code matches that text.

My regex:

```
string pattern = @"(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|(?:Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec)))\1|(?:(?:1|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2]|(?:Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})|(?:29(\/|-|\.)(?:0?2|(?:Feb))\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))|(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9]|(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep))|(?:1[0-2]|(?:Oct|Nov|Dec)))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})(?:[\D]*)(?<time>\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\s(?:A|P)M)";
```

The sentence would supposedly look like this:

```
Hello, meet me 5/1/2019 at 6:32 PM and then 5/2/2019 7:32 PM bye.
```

The regex should match:

1) `5/1/2019`

2) `6:32 PM`

3) `5/2/2019`

4) `7:32 PM`

Currently, this is what the output looks like:

```
Parsed 'Hello, meet me 5/1/2019 at 6:32 PM and then 5/2/2019 7:32 PM bye.' to 5/1/2019 at 6:32 PM.
Unable to convert 'Hello, meet me 5/1/2019 at 6:32 PM and then 5/2/2019 7:32 PM bye.' to a date.
Parsed 'Hello, meet me 5/1/2019 at 6:32 PM and then 5/2/2019 7:32 PM bye.' to 5/2/2019 7:32 PM.
Converted 'Hello, meet me 5/1/2019 at 6:32 PM and then 5/2/2019 7:32 PM bye.' to 05/02/2019 19:32:00.
```

> **Notice**:
>
> The *at* between 5/1/2019 and 6:32 was accepted and it shouldn't be.

Please let any answers be somewhat related to my regex as it is a requirement to use it.

Comment: In that question, you were told to break up the alternations and test each piece individually, until everything was working.  You haven't taken any advice from that question.

Comment: This is exact same question as you posted the other day... Please, don't mess this forum [Extract Date and Time from a String Using Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52070511/extract-date-and-time-from-a-string-using-regex)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am unable to break it down. It only works in full. I attempted and it wouldn't work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen actually my last question was meant to recognize another date in the same string which I solved. This issue is slightly different

Comment: You can test your regex here: https://regex101.com/ and as far as I know, there is no way to make a 'single selection' removing something inside *(in your case the 'at')*. In my opinion, the regex is too complicated and too unstable. Try to simplify it and parse date and time separately, not as a single block.

Answer (score 0):

It's my first c# program don't be cruel:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace myApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "Hello, meet me 5/1/2019 at 6:32 PM and then 5/2/2019 7:32 PM bye.";
            Regex word = new Regex(@"(([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}\s[A-Z]{2})|([0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}))");
            MatchCollection mc = word.Matches(input);
            foreach (Match m in mc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
5/1/2019
6:32 PM
5/2/2019
7:32 PM
```